# \footnotetext and \footnotemark do not work in table environment

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have some issues in the using of `\footnote` in a table. My code is as follows, in which I use the packages `\usepackage{footnote}` and `\usepackage{tabularx}`. But the text of footnote is not shown below the table, where only the superscript "1" and "2" appear aside the relevant items. I need the superscript shown as "a", "b", "c",...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename 
\ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-3\baselineskip}{20pt}[3.7cm]

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\tolerance=2500
\usepackage{longtable}
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{nomentbl}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}\linespread{1.6}
\setlength\parskip{3pt plus 1.5pt minus 1.5pt}%paragraph

\begin{document}
Some text here, as listed in Table~\ref{tab}.

\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \caption{Caption of the table}\label{tab}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lccc}
  \toprule
       x11            &x12 \footnotemark[1]   &x13 \footnotemark[2]    &x14 \footnotemark[2] \\
       \midrule
       x21            &x22                    &x23                     &x24                  \\
       x31            &x32 \footnotemark[1]   &x33 \footnotemark[1]    &x34                  \\
       \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \footnotetext[1]{This is the 1st footnote}%
  \footnotetext[2]{This is the 2nd footnote}%
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

**update:** I have corrected the code according to the comment of @ Skillmon.

Comment: If you include `booktabs` maybe you should use it for the horizontal lines in your table. You should use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` instead of the two `\hline`s and `\midrule` for the one beneath the table's headrow. And your MWE is missing the package `tabularx`.

Comment: And don't use `\label` inside of `\caption` but after it.

Comment: @ Skillmon thanks for your very useful suggestion. After correction, the footnotes still do not appear...

Comment: enclose table in in `minipage`

Comment: @Zarko, Sorry, may be it is a very easy and obvious problem for others. I don't very understand how to use the `minipage`. Could you please show it in my code? Thanks!

Comment: @Zarko don't enclose the `table` in `minipage` but the `tabular`

Comment: @Skillmon, with table i think on table in float `table`, in OP case, it use `tabulary` .. :). see my answer below.

Comment: @Zarko I know what you meant, but your formulation suggests something like `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{table*}` which would not work.

Comment: @Skillmon inside the caption (at the end) is better than after it, in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

beside `threeparttable` you can use "classic" approach as I mentioned in comment above:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.7cm,right=2.5cm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
Some text here, as listed in Table~\ref{tab}.

\begin{table*}[ht]
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \renewcommand\footnoterule{}
        \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
  \caption{Caption of the table}\label{tab}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xccc}
  \toprule
       x11            &x12 \footnotemark[1]   &x13 \footnotemark[2]    &x14 \footnotemark[2] \\
       \midrule
       x21            &x22                    &x23                     &x24                  \\
       x31            &x32 \footnotemark[1]   &x33 \footnotemark[1]    &x34                  \\
       \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
      \vspace{-1.5ex}% <-- added
  \footnotetext[1]{This is the 1st footnote}%
  \footnotetext[2]{This is the 2nd footnote}%
    \end{minipage}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

note:
if you use `tabularx` environment for table, than at least one column had to be `X` type.

Comment: @Skillmon, no. if i do such, `footnotemark`s in table are numbers bit at `footnotext` are letters.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The table now occupies one new page. However, I hope it can fit in a page together with the text.

Comment: @jsxs, of course now your table are taller and require more space on page, however both answers solve your footnote problem :), so remove acceptance of one of them because of new problem which is not concern of this question, is not very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Floating environments (`table`, `figure`) do not support footnotes.
There are several workarounds, e.g. wrapping the `tabular` in a `minipage`.
Another option is offered by package `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}[b]
    \caption{Caption of the table}\label{tab}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
      \toprule
      header11 &x12\tnote{a} &x13\tnote{b} &x14\tnote{b} \\
      \midrule
      dummy21 &x22          &x23          &x24 \\
      hello31 &x32\tnote{a} &x33\tnote{a} &x34 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \item[a] This is the 1st footnote.
      \item[b] This is the 2nd footnote.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution. I can only accept one answer, which allows the footnote below the table numbered by letter rather than number.

Comment: @jsxs There is nothing special about the marker, just switch to letters as in the updated answer.

Comment: @ Heiko Oberdiek, With either your or Zarko's solutions, the table occupies one new page. I hope it can fit in a page together with the text.